# SQL - Getting the exact one that's heard of a comma separation

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress

I would like to get the exact data set from my database. As an example, I'll select a number in the front end. This should look in the database to see if it exists and give me the exact data set afterwards, but I only got it with a LIKE statement and this gives me 2 data sets from which is not correct. The values are seperated with a comma.

Here is a code example:

```
$results   = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * 
                                  FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . "imports 
                                  WHERE import_strassennamen = '" . $_POST['street'] . "' 
                                  AND import_anzahl_strassen LIKE '%," . $_POST['street_nr'] . ",%' 
                                  AND import_year = '" . $_POST['year'] . "'", OBJECT );
```

The names are in German because I come from Germany.

Now the example for a data record that occurs twice, but has a different so-called "area".

[image]

For example, you can select a street number in a select field in the front end, and this should then be found for the area.

For example, if you select 4 in the frontend, the area with the number 3 will be selected. Or if you select number 17, area 2 is selected.

Comment: Does the data in your database have the same structure as in the image? For example, the first record has the string "17,18,19,20,21..." assigned to the `area` field, with commas and all?

Comment: @RaulSauco Yes, it has the same structure

Comment: @RaulSauco For example, "Hauptstraße" is the import_straßenname and "2" is the area field and "17,18,19,20,21..." is the import_anzahl_straßen. I hope this clear it out.

Comment: I am sure the WordPress devs have done everything to secure their code against [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). But you have just destroyed all that. You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes you are right. I should use this. I never really used this one yet in my code. But my problem is another.

Comment: So in what case are you getting more records than expected then? What input value for the street number did you use, that gets you the record with area=2 here as well, although you only expected to get the one with area=3?

Comment: Oh the good old comma delimited information database design mistake.

Comment: @CBroe So when i select for example "4" i get area 2 and area 3 because "4" is in import_anzahl_straßen multiple. So "4" is in "40" or "42". What i want is, that when i select "4" i only get "4" of area "3" and nothing else out of area "2". I hope you understand that.

Comment: _“So `4` is in `40` or `42`”_ - but `,4,` is what you have in your query, and that is _not_ in `40`or `42`. I think your mistake here is that you included the `%` before and after the value - if I am not mistaken, you are not supposed to do that when using the `LIKE` comparison operator with wp_query, WordPress will add those before and after the specified value itself.

Comment: @CBroe I tested it and i became a null array back after that.

Comment: `WHERE find_in_set(4, import_anzahl_strassen);` Does that work for you

Comment: Oh, sorry, scratch that, you are not using WP_Query here, but building the query yourself, so this didn’t apply.

Comment: Yes, FIND_IN_SET is really the best option then - then you don’t have to add any commas to the value yourself.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Nah i became again a null array back of it.

Comment: `REGEXP '(," . $_POST['street_nr'] . ")|(" . $_POST['street_nr'] . ",)"` ? I posted it originally as an answer, but it is such a hack that I deleted it.

Comment: @RaulSauco I became again a null array back from that. Sorry for the drouble with this question.

Comment: Are you checking the error log, my guess is you are messing up the quoted literal with these changes

Comment: Check the generated SQL, regexp should work, for example, for a value of `4`, like in your example, the SQL should be like this: `select * from table where column regexp '(,4)|(4,)'`. You can try on the mysql command line to see that it works.

Comment: @RaulSauco And again i became a zero array and no error in log. REGEXP gives me nothing out of it

Comment: @RaulSauco So i tested a bit with your comment and i found out that it worked but i was to dump to implemented it. But i became the same value out as LIKE. Is this right?

Comment: You are right, sorry, I gave you the wrong regex pattern, it will still match when the 4 is next to the coma, for example 24,44,48 and such. Maybe easier to match **word boundaries** thus: `\\b4\\b`. Even so, this is probably the worst solution, `FIND_IN_SET` seems like a better option, and best would be to have that structure built into the database. Good luck!

Comment: @RaulSauco I posted my own solutiion for this problem down below. Thx for your help. And sorry for the problems.

Answer (score 0):

After long discussions with some members i have made my own solution for this problem. Its not the elegant way but i made it at the end:

```
if ( $_POST['street_nr'] == '4' && $_POST['street'] == 'Hauptstraße' ) {
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . "imports WHERE import_strassennamen = '" . $_POST['street'] . "' AND import_anzahl_strassen LIKE '4,%' AND import_year = '" . $_POST['year'] . "'", OBJECT );
    } elseif ( $_POST['street_nr'] == '6' && $_POST['street'] == 'Hauptstraße' || $_POST['street_nr'] == '7' && $_POST['street'] == 'Hauptstraße' || $_POST['street_nr'] == '8' && $_POST['street'] == 'Hauptstraße' || $_POST['street_nr'] == '9' && $_POST['street'] == 'Hauptstraße' ) {
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . "imports WHERE import_strassennamen = '" . $_POST['street'] . "' AND import_anzahl_strassen LIKE '%," . $_POST['street_nr'] . ",%' AND import_year = '" . $_POST['year'] . "'", OBJECT );
    } else {
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . "imports WHERE import_strassennamen = '" . $_POST['street'] . "' AND import_anzahl_strassen REGEXP '(," . $_POST['street_nr'] . ')|(' . $_POST['street_nr'] . ",)' and import_year = '" . $_POST['year'] . "'", OBJECT );
    }
```

I have made a distinction in PHP to fire up other SQLs. I know its not the fastest and secured way at all, but it works. If anyone has a better solution for this problem i would highly recommend it. Such as SQL Solution.